# Cheap Android watch with at least 24 hour battery life

Tags: android, wearable-technology, cheap

I bought [the cheapest that Amazon has](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Electronics-Bluetooth-select-Android-Samsung-models/dp/B00KARD0D2/) and found that the battery only lasted a few hours.

I would prefer to charge once a week, might accept once per day, but no less.

No fancy features are necessary (maybe notification of incoming calls & SMS), as I want it primarily for telling the time, but also to program my own apps.

My budget is tight, can anyone recommend a cheap Android watch with decent battery life, which they have personally used for a while (maybe even programmed)?

Anyone at all?

---

[Update] Almost three years later, has anything changed?
Surely there must be something for now? I would prefer sub-$50, but I can be somewhat flexible.

I need to be able to add my own app to it, and it must have either WiFi or Bluetooth, preferably BTLE.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably find a used Samsung Gear S2 in great condition for around $45 to $75, I know I have.

Take a look at [Craigslist](http://craigslist.org) or your local similar sites.

The Samsung Gear S2 is a great watch that is programmable through [Samsung Developers](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch) and has a lot of downloadable apps and watch faces to choose from.